# Can't add LINQ to ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net

I've got a simple ASP.NET website, but I can't get it to work. The server is running IIS 7.5 with .NET 4.0 installed, and I've got complete access, and I'm using VS2010 to generate an ASP.NET 4 website. But VS automatically generates code-behind files with `using System.Linq;` in them. This wouldn't be a problem for me except it doesn't seem to reference Linq by default. I added in the IIS Manager/site/.NET Compilation/Assemblies list the System.Data.Linq assembly, *and* I added a reference to it in the web config, but it's still complaining that `System.Linq` does not exist.

The website works fine on my home machine where I'm developing it with VS2010 installed.

What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are mixing up `System.Linq` the overall Linq library and `System.Data.Linq` : linq2sql?

Comment: Your question is vague. What is it you can't do? Can't you query the database using LINQ to SQL or can't you write LINQ queries in code? What is the actual error?

Comment: The question states that ASP.NET is saying that `System.Linq` does not exist, and I tried to solve it by adding references- kinda implies undefined reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default application pool is 2.0, rather than 4.0 (unhelpful default), which also explains why VS2010 ran it fine- it knew that it was a 4.0 application. Once I changed this, everything is working smoothly.